# Using Pix4d google_tiles KML outside of Google Earth

Tags: leaflet, google-maps-api, gdal2tiles, pix4d

I am using Pix4d to generate orthomosaic tiles.   I would like to display these in something other than the HTML that is provided.   Possibly have 2 or three shown on the same window.   The full orthomosaic is huge (101 GB) and can only be opened in QGIS or ArcGIS or other software packages.  I tried to use Leaflet but it does not seem to be able to handle the KML with the file structure.   I may be doing something wrong.

1. https://support.pix4d.com/hc/en-us/articles/206860936-How-to-generate-the-Google-Maps-Tiles-and-KML
2. https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates

Is there a clear direction on how to use these tiles other than open them with the supplied HTML file (which works well for this single file)?

[Image of the file structure of google_tiles[image: ][1]]

[image]

Comment: There seems to be no Leaflet plugin to handle Google combination of .png and .kml tiles. Without writing your own rendering methods you can only show .png tiles in Leaflet.

Comment: TomazicM  - Thanks   I will look at writing something that will create what leaflet needs.  I can make word files but it looks like I need more than that.

Comment: I just ran gdal2tiles on a very large geotif file and it worked fantastic!  It generates the leaflet, googlemaps and openlayers html code so all you have to do is pick what you want.   This video explains it and also the gdal2tiles.py docs.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7do_whEkI0&t=7s